# using prettyPhoto plugin I can not load video from my server?

Tags: php, jquery, html, prettyphoto

If I use prettyPhoto, I can show the Despicable Me preview, and I can show youtube videos. But I cannot show a video from my own server. It either doesn't load, or an error message pops up that says either my path is incorrect or the image doesn't exist.

This is with both rel="prettyPhoto" and rel="prettyPhoto[movies]". Note: I do NOT want to embed a YouTube video with the YouTube logo.

If I delete rel="prettyPhoto" and use `<iframe>` tags instead, the same video I could not show with prettyPhoto DOES work. So, therefore, the path IS correct, and the movie DOES exist on my server.

BUT if I use this option the video is trapped within the frame, which is too small for the video's resolution and therefore not the option I want to use. I want to use prettyPhoto for the awesome effect it provides.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettyPhoto/3.1.6/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettyPhoto/3.1.6/css/prettyPhoto.css" />

<a href="https://axelta-monitor.s3.amazonaws.com/AX_Guard%2520Patrolling%2520Demo_AXB052_1499909053_008.mp4" title="View" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]">View</a>
```

Comment: Without any code examples, nope-

Comment: I edit my question with code

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you with relevant stuff and expected and actual result

Comment: but it can not display with popup as pettyPhoto give the effect

Comment: Any other solution  @mplungjan ?

Comment: I have no idea what your problem is. You need to update your question with something that shows a problem

Comment: I want to show video  like this demo http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/HU8zx/ .But my video is not youtube video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You DO need to use the iFrame and you can resize to whatever your content is

I added `?iframe=true&width=200&height=200` to the URL

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/y1zz9car/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/wp-content/themes/NMFE/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/wp-content/themes/NMFE/css/prettyPhoto.css">

<div id="video_player">
  <a href="https://axelta-monitor.s3.amazonaws.com/AX_Guard%2520Patrolling%2520Demo_AXB052_1499909053_008.mp4?iframe=true&width=200&height=200" rel="prettyPhoto" title="My private Video">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/cH6kxtzovew/default.jpg" alt="My image" width="50">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but It does not show thumbnail at bottom

Comment: What do you mean by "thumbnail at bottom" ?

Answer (score 1):

I want thumbnail at bottom like. It does not apply

[image]

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting a question as an answer